# Why do vinyl gloves work on my touch screen, while other objects don't?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, electronics

If I use a rubber or plastic object on the screen of my smartphone (Galaxy S5), the digitizer does not register the contact.

According to my understanding, the reason it registers fingers but not plastic is because fingers conduct electricity, and thus disturb an electromagnetic field on the surface of the screen.

I wear these vinyl gloves at work.

[image]

[image]

The digitizer still registers my touches even while I'm wearing these gloves. It seems to work nearly as well as it does without gloves.

Now, I believe that vinyl can be used as an insulator, and I don't think it's conducts electricity very much.

So why does the digitizer still register my touches while I'm wearing these gloves, but not touches from a plastic or rubber object?

I believe the gloves are 100% vinyl.

Comment: The touchscreen senses changes in capacitance. No conductive path to your fingers is required. That is also why you can put a plastic/glass protective shield onto your screen and it still works.

Comment: @Alexander OK. So what I am trying to understand is, why doesn't a plastic or rubber object do this?

Comment: A plastic object also changes the electric field (Vinyl for example has a dielectric constant of 2-4) but this change is much smaller than the change from your finger (which is connected to your whole body). The physics behind this is really just a change in capacitance by bringing an object close to the small conducting traces in the screen. The harder part is the electronics behind it (https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1612/1612.08227.pdf)